# How to have a many-to-many relationship between ASP.NET Identity Core users and a custom external table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project running IdentityServer4 on top of ASP.NET Identity Core as described [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html). This project has its own separate SQL Server database to store the ASP.NET Identity Core tables.

Then I have a bunch of other projects, including an ASP.NET Core 2.1 API that is protected by the IdentityServer. These projects talks to another SQL Server database which contains all the web app specific data.

I want to express a many-to-many relationship between users (living in the IdentityServer database) and tenants (living in the app database).

I'm thinking of several possibilities:

1. Add one or more claims to each user specifying access to tenants. So basically each user would have a claim of type `tenant` with the value being the ID of the tenant.
   So when I need to get all the tenants the user has access to in the API, I can just do `IEnumerable<Claim> tenants = User.FindAll("tenant")`.
   This feels "dirty" because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1) says:

> A claim is a name value pair that represents what the subject is, not
>   what the subject can do.

2. Another option would be to have an Users table in the app database with each record having a reference to the ID of the ASP.NET Identity Core user. And from that table, create a normal many-to-many relationship in the app database.
   This makes thing easier to manage but I'd need to enforce a 1-1 mapping between the user in the IdentityServer database and the one in the app database.

Can you think of a better way to solve this? If not, would you go with option 1 or 2?

Comment: This question could be more welcome in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, having said that, i would go with option 2, it is more extensible, and you can easily enforce the 1-1 mapping with code

Comment: I think that the scenario that you describe is one where "having access to tenant X" is a like a "role" that a user may or not have. An option would be to describe the tenants a user has access to has roles in the IDS database. Still I would prefer to use scenario 2 because claims are not well suited to describe permissions and using roles becomes tricky because the IDS now would have a dependency on an "external concept".